# Image Mosaic (Bootstrap and NuxtJS)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build the image mosaic using Bootstrap, CSS and NuxtJS. I have five images and the first one must be in the center. Two images are on the left side and two images are on the right side relative to the first image (all images are square). This is my code but I have some issues with the mobile and desktop design (must be responsive design) and don't know how to center the first image. Does anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

```
  <div class="container d-flex flex-md-column flex-lg-row">
    <div class="small-tiles flex-md-row flex-lg-column">
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/image2.png"
        alt="The second image"
      />
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/image3.png"
        alt="The third image"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="center-tile d-flex flex-column">
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/image1.png"
        alt="The first image"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="small-tiles flex-md-row flex-lg-column">
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/image4.png"
        alt="The fourth image"
      />
      <img
        src="../../assets/images/image5.png"
        alt="The fiveth image"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.small-tiles {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 576) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.center-tile {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 576) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want all the images to be the same size?

Comment: Yes, I do. All the images must to be the same size

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the images as well as being square are all the same size, this snippet produces this layout using pure CSS:

[image]

The grid has 3 columns. The first has two areas, the middle has one and the third has two. Images are shown as backgrounds to each area. Obviously you will want to alter the gap and the general sizing to whatever you require.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 30%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'pictl piccenter pictr' 'pictl piccenter pictr' 'picbl piccenter picbr' 'picbl piccenter picbr';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

*[class^="pic"] {
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}

.pic1 {
  grid-area: pictl;
}


/* top left */

.pic2 {
  grid-area: picbl;
}


/* bottom left */

.pic3 {
  grid-area: piccenter;
}


/* center */

.pic4 {
  grid-area: pictr;
}


/* top right */

.pic5 {
  grid-area: picbr;
}


/* bottom right */

.pic1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200);
}

.pic2 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/200);
}

.pic3 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/200);
}

.pic4 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/200/200);
}

.pic5 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1022/200/200);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="pic1"></div>
  <div class="pic2"></div>
  <div class="pic3"></div>
  <div class="pic4"></div>
  <div class="pic5"></div>
</div>
```